# Examples from Net::RabbitMQ not working

Tags: perl, rabbitmq, anyevent

I'm trying to learn RabbitMQ for a project I'm working on. My research showed two libraries to use, Net::RabbitMQ and AnyEvent::RabbitMQ.  AnyEvent::RabbitMQ seems overly baroque for my needs but Net::RabbitMQ does not appear to work as the examples show it should.
Below is some example code I found, it matches what I saw in the POD, but it isn't working.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Net::RabbitMQ;

{

    # closure to return a new channel ID every time we call nextchan
    my $nextchan = 1;
    sub nextchan { return $nextchan++ }
}

### BEGIN CONFIGURABLE PARAMETERS ######################################
my $qserver = q{xx.xx.xx.xx};
my %qparms  = ();

my $qname   = q{gravity.checks};
my $message = q{Test injection};
### NO CONFIGURABLE PARAMETERS BELOW THIS LINE #########################

my $mq     = Net::RabbitMQ->new();
my $chanID = nextchan();
$message .= " " . scalar(localtime);

print STDERR qq{Will try to send message "$message" through channel $chanID};

$mq->connect( $qserver, %qparms );
```

It errors out :

```
  $. / send . pl
  Will try to send message "Test injection Fri Nov 14 06:50:44 2014" through channel 1 Usage : Net::RabbitMQ::connect( conn, hostname, options ) at . /send.pl line 28.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `%qparams` need to be passed by reference and not directly. The change line 28 to :

```
$mq->connect($qserver, \%qparms) ;
```

Solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't error out. It prints to STDERR without checking if an error occured. It says I'll try and then it does:

```
$mq->connect( $qserver, %qparms );
```

This is just an information, not an error.

Comment: At the end of the line is the error: Usage : Net::RabbitMQ::connect( conn, hostname, options ) at . /send.pl line 28. I figured out my problem...

Comment: Just because I'm blind ;)